# RestKit get count of ignored objects through KVC in mapping result

Tags: ios, restkit, kvc

Is there a way to differ between mapping results which are empty due to there being no data do map att the key path and a mapping result which is empty due do skipping objects through KVC.

The problem I have is that I am working with a API which is not very well thought through, and I need to find a way to know when I am at the end of the page. The issue is that there is a possibility that the mapping result can be empty due to all the objects being returned are "deleted".

TLDR; Is there a way to see the amount of mapping errors through mapping result on a completed request.

EDIT

I solved my own problem by reading the documentation again. The solution was to create a subclass of RKObjectRequestOperation and then register it.

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] registerRequestOperationClass:[CustomRequestOperation class]];
```

This mean that I could implement the following which would listen to mapping errors and increment a counter and add it to mappingMetaData when the mapping completed.

```
- (void)setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:(void ( ^ ) ( RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , RKMappingResult *mappingResult ))success failure:(void (^) ( RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , NSError *error ))failure {

    __block typeof(skipCount) temp = skipCount;
    [super setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^void(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        if (success) {
            operation.mappingMetadata = @{@"skipCount" : @(temp)};
            success(operation, mappingResult);
        }

    } failure:^void(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , NSError *error) {
        if (failure) {
            failure(operation, error);
        }
    }];
}

- (void)mapper:(RKMapperOperation *)mapper didFailMappingOperation:(RKMappingOperation *)mappingOperation forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath withError:(NSError *)error {
    skipCount++;
}

- (void)mapperWillStartMapping:(RKMapperOperation *)mapper {
    skipCount = 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think so, I expect you'd need to fork and add this.

Comment: Yeah that was what I was thinking, but wanted to  check before I got started.